# How to Declare A Vector of a User-Defined Type in VHDL?

Tags: overloading, vhdl

I'm trying to make an overload package so I can use the RIT datatype to design a 32-bit multiplier. The RIT datatype, as I've defined it below, can take either a 1, a 0, or a high impedance value (Z).

The functions seem to be all I require, but I can't figure out how to overload it to recognize vectors as well like STD_LOGIC and BIT data types can. Can anyone point me in the right direction? My overload package "rit_overload_package" as it stands is below:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

PACKAGE rit_overload_package IS

TYPE rit IS('0','1','Z');
TYPE rit_table_2D IS array(rit,rit) OF rit;
TYPE rit_table_1D IS array(rit) OF rit;

 CONSTANT rit_and_table: rit_table_2D := 
--    0     1    Z
 (('0',  '0', '0'),   -- 0
  ('0',  '1', '1'),   -- 1
  ('0',  '1', 'Z'));  -- Z)  

 CONSTANT rit_or_table: rit_table_2D := 
 --    0     1    Z
 (('0',  '1', '0'),   -- 0
  ('1',  '1', '1'),   -- 1
  ('0',  '1', 'Z'));  -- Z) 

 CONSTANT rit_not_table: rit_table_1D := 
--    0   1   Z
  (('1','0','Z'));    

 FUNCTION "AND"(a,b:rit) RETURN rit;
 FUNCTION "OR"(a,b:rit) RETURN rit;
 FUNCTION "NOT"(a:rit) RETURN rit;

 END rit_overload_package;

 PACKAGE BODY rit_overload_package IS

 FUNCTION "AND" (a,b:rit) RETURN rit IS

 BEGIN
 RETURN rit_and_table(a,b);

 END "AND";

 FUNCTION "OR" (a,b:rit) RETURN rit IS

 BEGIN
 RETURN rit_or_table(a,b);

 END "OR";

 FUNCTION "NOT" (a:rit) RETURN rit IS

 BEGIN
 RETURN rit_not_table(a);

 END "NOT";

 END rit_overload_package;
```

Comment: You are aware that std_logic(_vector) already contains a high impedance 'Z' state?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing function overload is to simply declare additional functions with the same name, but with different argument signatures.  So if you want AND for another type `myt`, then you can just add in the declaration:

```
FUNCTION "AND"(a,b:myt) RETURN myt;
```

And then of course also implement the functionality.

All combinations of arguments must be explicitly declared, and implemented.

If you need functions to return different result types for the same arguments, then the function name must be different, like declaring and implementing for example `AND_rit` and `AND_myt` where the arguments can then be the same type, but where the result may differ.

Answer (score 0):

A "vector" is just a type defined as an array of scalars. You just need to define your vector type first (for variable-length vectors, the conventional way is to use `natural range <>` for the array range), then define another overload as you've already done for your scalar type.